# MS Outlook, auto update field

Tags: outlook

I'm new to MS Outlook, so I apologise if this is a really daft question.
I have created a very basic table in outlook. In one cell I have a qty (the qty can be manually changed) and another cell another qty (again this can be manually changed).
I have bookmarked the first cell (named: UNIT) and am using a formula to multiply the 2 values

```
=PRODUCT(LEFT,UNIT)
```

This issue I have is; when one or both of the values are amended the formula only recalculates once I manually update the field (right click the cell and select 'update field).

Is there a way to automate the field to recalculate the formula when one or both of the values are amended?

I'm OK with VBA coding in excel, but cannot figure out how to do this in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

I have used an embedded excel workbook, much easier!